# Where/when are exit statuses returned for background jobs in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, parallelism, failure-resistance

I'm writing a bash script which has many parts, but I want built in resiliency and parallel processing as much as possible. An example is below:

```
while true
do
  var=$(curl someurl) || continue
  var2=$(curl someurl2) || continue
  var3=$(curl someurl3) || continue
  dosomething var1 || continue
  dosomething2 var2 || continue
  dosomething3 var3 || continue
  break
done
```

I'd like to run the 3 curl commands in parallel, and then the three "do something" commands in parallel as well. However, I'm not sure how this would be handled. I considered inserting the `wait` command after each block and inserting `&` after each command as follows:

```
while true
do
  var=$(curl someurl) & || continue
  var2=$(curl someurl2) & || continue
  var3=$(curl someurl3) & || continue
  wait
  dosomething var1 & || continue
  dosomething2 var2 & || continue
  dosomething3 var3 & || continue
  wait
  break
done
```

However, in this situation, I'm not sure how the exit statuses and/or race conditions could be managed. Additionally, this doesn't seem like best coding practices. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: I think parallelism, as basically a performance concern, is not best handled in `bash`; if performance becomes an issue, it's usually best to move to a more sophisticated language.

Comment: Depending on your requirements you could restructure it as (var1=...; dosomething $var1) &; ditto var2 & var3; wait; wait; wait.

Answer (score 2):

Bash doesn't let you capture the output of a something in the background.

```
$ unset var; var=$(sh -c 'sleep 5; echo foo; exit 42') 
$ echo $? $var 
42 foo
$ unset var; var=$(sh -c 'sleep 5; echo foo; exit 42') & wait
[1] 30250
[1]+  Exit 42                 var=$(sh -c 'sleep 5; echo foo; exit 42')
$ echo $? $var 
0
```

There is `wait -n` which returns when *some* background process has ended, and it exits with that process's exit status. Since you know how many background processes you have, you can `wait -n` that many times. Ugly, but...

```
while true
do
  curl someurl1 > file1 &
  curl someurl2 > file2 &
  curl someurl3 > file3 &
  for i in 1 2 3; do
    wait -n || { echo some curl failed; continue 2; }
  done

  dosomething "$(< file1)" &
  dosomething "$(< file2)" &
  dosomething "$(< file3)" &
  for i in 1 2 3; do
    wait -n || { echo some dosomething failed; continue 2; }
  done

  break
done
```

Comment: Is there perhaps a better command or built in function than `wait` which could be used? This seems ugly as well as just poor programming principles in general. That, or maybe there's a completely different code structure that could be used?